# python selenium move_to_element_with_offset, passing in float offset

Tags: python, selenium

The following code, moves to the mid point of the element & performs the click

```
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
action_chains.move_to_element_with_offset(element, 33.8333, 0).click().perform()
```

But the following code, actually clicks at 34px from the top right corner of the element(which is desired).

```
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
action_chains.move_to_element_with_offset(element, 34, 0).click().perform()
```

But I want to actually click at 33.8333 px from the top-right corner, are there any issues if I pass in float values instead of integers ? Any workarounds or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the specific case you are facing, but I have heard of people struggling with similar issues. If I were you, I would look for a `javascript` solution in conjuntion with `driver.execute_async_script`